# Open a Dart app from webstorm

Tags: dart, webstorm

I've start using the Dart plugin for webstorm and wonder how can I open a Dart Application. I'm also looking for some documentaion of the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [screen cast](http://www.screenr.com/L3r8). You can jump to 2:05 and see specifically what you're looking for in IdeaJ 11. Basically you have to configure the Chrome web browser to use Chromium in the dart SDK instead. You will also need to add a configuration to your project by taking the following steps:

1. Select 'Edit Configurations...' from the Run menu.
2. Click the + icon to add a new configuration and Choose Dart Application
3. You will be prompted to select the HTML page that is the start of your app.

These are for using a web page as you implied you're doing in your comment, they are slightly different for a command line app, but I think you'll see the differences clearly if you follow these steps.

NOTE: For the most recent dart plugin releases I found that I had to download [IdeaJ 12 Preview/EAP known as Leda](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP). However, it seems an older version of the dart plugin are available and working on IdeaJ 11.

Comment: I have installed the plugin, the question is how to use it. Like "How can I open chromium, from within the IDE"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand completely the first time. AFAICT the settings for setting up a debug config are the same as with other IdeaJ project types., I have updated the answer to include that info though. Hope it helps.